# Upgrading The cedar-14 stack Stack in Heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, upgrade

Am running a RoR stack on Heroku (Ruby, PostgreSQL, Node.JS).  The current stack is cedar-14 and I am being prompted to upgrade the stack.  I am running a standard pipeline (dev, staging, production) and want to clarify if there is a logical order to upgrade the three apps in?

Should I upgrade the 'dev' app first (and check for problems)?  Heroku says that the app will need to be redeployed after the upgrade and I want to check that upgrading won't break the pipeline links?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... You're asking if you should check functionality in dev before checking in prod?

Comment: It was two questions really (sorry) - should I check for upgrade problems in one of the apps in the pipeline first (and if so, is there a recommended order)?   Also, it says if I upgrade an app I will need to 'redeploy' it.  I wanted to make sure that this didn't break the pipeline - meaning I would have to re-attach it to the pipeline?   Thanks in advance for the help! Nigel